# How to get the next complete string after the match using grep?

Tags: regex, grep

I am using grep (on Windows 7) to look through a directory of VB source files. I want to extract information about the names of the forms that those source files contain. So, I tried this -

```
grep -in "VB.form" *.*
```

However, this gives me results as follows -

```
 A.frm:3:Begin VB.Form frmPQR
 B.frm:2:Begin VB.Form frmXYZ
 C.frm:3:Begin VB.Form frmLMN
 D.frm:2:Begin VB.Form frmRST
 ...
```

How can I write the command such that I get only this -

```
 A.frm:frmPQR
 B.frm:frmXYZ
 C.frm:frmLMN
 D.frm:frmRST
 ...
```

Comment: which grep tool are you using?

Comment: I don't remember. It came as grep.exe with a few other DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

pipe the output to `awk 'BEGIN{FS="[: ]"} {print $1":"$NF}'`